# Get Text of dynamically created html row on touch in Cordova App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, dynamic-tables

I am trying to select and get value of dynamically created row using javascript/jquery. I have tried multiple things they work on browser but not on IOS mobile. I have tried .click, .live, .on , .tap functions and the app doesn't seem to recognize any of these when clicking on the rows of dynamically created table. Below are some snippets I tried and were placed in Device.ready(). Any suggestions on this is appreciated.

Snippet 1:

```
 $("#TblInspectionData tr").click(function () {
                alert("RowClicked")
            });
```

Snippet2:

```
 $('#TblInspectionData tr').live('click', function () {
                alert("RowClicked");
            });
```

snippet 3:

```
$("#TblInspectionData tr").on("tap", function () {
            alert("RowClicked");
        });
```

snippet4:

```
$("#TblInspectionData tr").on("click", function () {
            alert("RowClicked");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase the rows don't exist yet when your javascript is executed, no events are added to them. If you want to dynamicly add the events, you have to add a selector to your [`on(`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

For example, like this:

```
$("#TblInspectionData").on("click", "tr", function () {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

The above code asumes `#TblInspectionData` is already in the DOM when the page is loaded. If not, you should add the closest parent of this element that is in your html.

Comment: Thank You @Jerodev this solved my issue. Really appreciate your help.